# Reading a tab delimited text file with leading tabs on some lines

Tags: c++, tabs

I am working to build a console-based spreadsheet app that takes in a UTF-8 encoded text file as input and outputs the results to the console.

Column values are separated by tabs and each new line is a new row. I am having some issues reading in the tab-delimited input text file where some of the lines (rows) are starting with a tab indicating that there is no value in the first column(s). I would like to just extract the "filled" cells and use the data elsewhere in the program and discard or ignore the "empty" cells. Using the '\t' delimiter in the `getline()` function does not seem to ignore these leading tabs. Thank you ahead of time for any help or code suggestions.

Example Input:

```
1 \t 2
\t 3
\t \t =A1+B1+B2
```

The simple code I've been using is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <string>

// Variable declarations
std::ifstream sheetFile;
std::string input;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sheetFile.open(argv[1]);
    while (getline(sheetFile, input, '\t'))
    {
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }

    sheetFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And the return to the console is:

```
1
2

3


=A1+B1+B2
```

Comment: _"Using the '\t' delimiter in the getline() function does not seem to ignore these leading tabs."_ Why would you expect it to do so? That's not what the function does, neither does the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `std::getline()` calls - one in the loop to read each line delimited by `\n`, and then put each line into a `std::istringstream` and use `std::getline()` on thaat stream to parse each column delimited on `\t`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Variable declarations
    std::ifstream sheetFile(argv[1]);
    std::string line, input;

    while (std::getline(sheetFile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (std::getline(iss, input, '\t'))
        {
            if (!input.empty())
                std::cout << input << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, using a single `std::getline()`, you can use the `std::ws` stream manipulator to ignore leading whitespace on each line, which will include `\t` and `\n` characters:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Variable declarations
    std::ifstream sheetFile(argv[1]);
    std::string input;

    while (std::getline(sheetFile >> std::ws, input, '\t'))
    {
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```